# How to fix a mobile version of range slider?

Tags: javascript, css, mozilla

I tried different versions of this idea, ~7 range sliders, and I like that variant more then others. Source

```
https://codepen.io/joosts/pen/rNLdxvK
```

```
<div class="min-max-slider" data-legendnum="3">
    <label for="min">Minimum price</label>
    <input id="min" class="min" name="min" type="range" step="1" min="300" max="3000" />
    <label for="max">Maximum price</label>
    <input id="max" class="max" name="max" type="range" step="1" min="300" max="3000" />
</div>
```

```
.min-max-slider {position: relative; width: 200px; text-align: center; margin-bottom: 50px;}
.min-max-slider > label {display: none;}
span.value {height: 1.7em; font-weight: bold; display: inline-block;}
span.value.lower::before {content: "€"; display: inline-block;}
span.value.upper::before {content: "- €"; display: inline-block; margin-left: 0.4em;}
.min-max-slider > .legend {display: flex; justify-content: space-between;}
.min-max-slider > .legend > * {font-size: small; opacity: 0.25;}
.min-max-slider > input {cursor: pointer; position: absolute;}

/* webkit specific styling */
.min-max-slider > input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  outline: none!important;
  background: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, transparent 30%, silver 30%, silver 60%, transparent 60%, transparent 100%);
}
.min-max-slider > input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none; /* Override default look */
  appearance: none;
  width: 14px; /* Set a specific slider handle width */
  height: 14px; /* Slider handle height */
  background: #eee; /* Green background */
  cursor: pointer; /* Cursor on hover */
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.min-max-slider > input::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {cursor: pointer;}
```

```
var thumbsize = 14;

function draw(slider,splitvalue) {

    /* set function vars */
    var min = slider.querySelector('.min');
    var max = slider.querySelector('.max');
    var lower = slider.querySelector('.lower');
    var upper = slider.querySelector('.upper');
    var legend = slider.querySelector('.legend');
    var thumbsize = parseInt(slider.getAttribute('data-thumbsize'));
    var rangewidth = parseInt(slider.getAttribute('data-rangewidth'));
    var rangemin = parseInt(slider.getAttribute('data-rangemin'));
    var rangemax = parseInt(slider.getAttribute('data-rangemax'));

    /* set min and max attributes */
    min.setAttribute('max',splitvalue);
    max.setAttribute('min',splitvalue);

    /* set css */
    min.style.width = parseInt(thumbsize + ((splitvalue - rangemin)/(rangemax - rangemin))*(rangewidth - (2*thumbsize)))+'px';
    max.style.width = parseInt(thumbsize + ((rangemax - splitvalue)/(rangemax - rangemin))*(rangewidth - (2*thumbsize)))+'px';
    min.style.left = '0px';
    max.style.left = parseInt(min.style.width)+'px';
    min.style.top = lower.offsetHeight+'px';
    max.style.top = lower.offsetHeight+'px';
    legend.style.marginTop = min.offsetHeight+'px';
    slider.style.height = (lower.offsetHeight + min.offsetHeight + legend.offsetHeight)+'px';
    
    /* correct for 1 off at the end */
    if(max.value>(rangemax - 1)) max.setAttribute('data-value',rangemax);

    /* write value and labels */
    max.value = max.getAttribute('data-value'); 
    min.value = min.getAttribute('data-value');
    lower.innerHTML = min.getAttribute('data-value');
    upper.innerHTML = max.getAttribute('data-value');

}

function init(slider) {
    /* set function vars */
    var min = slider.querySelector('.min');
    var max = slider.querySelector('.max');
    var rangemin = parseInt(min.getAttribute('min'));
    var rangemax = parseInt(max.getAttribute('max'));
    var avgvalue = (rangemin + rangemax)/2;
    var legendnum = slider.getAttribute('data-legendnum');

    /* set data-values */
    min.setAttribute('data-value',rangemin);
    max.setAttribute('data-value',rangemax);
    
    /* set data vars */
    slider.setAttribute('data-rangemin',rangemin); 
    slider.setAttribute('data-rangemax',rangemax); 
    slider.setAttribute('data-thumbsize',thumbsize); 
    slider.setAttribute('data-rangewidth',slider.offsetWidth);

    /* write labels */
    var lower = document.createElement('span');
    var upper = document.createElement('span');
    lower.classList.add('lower','value');
    upper.classList.add('upper','value');
    lower.appendChild(document.createTextNode(rangemin));
    upper.appendChild(document.createTextNode(rangemax));
    slider.insertBefore(lower,min.previousElementSibling);
    slider.insertBefore(upper,min.previousElementSibling);
    
    /* write legend */
    var legend = document.createElement('div');
    legend.classList.add('legend');
    var legendvalues = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < legendnum; i++) {
        legendvalues[i] = document.createElement('div');
        var val = Math.round(rangemin+(i/(legendnum-1))*(rangemax - rangemin));
        legendvalues[i].appendChild(document.createTextNode(val));
        legend.appendChild(legendvalues[i]);

    } 
    slider.appendChild(legend);

    /* draw */
    draw(slider,avgvalue);

    /* events */
    min.addEventListener("input", function() {update(min);});
    max.addEventListener("input", function() {update(max);});
}

function update(el){
    /* set function vars */
    var slider = el.parentElement;
    var min = slider.querySelector('#min');
    var max = slider.querySelector('#max');
    var minvalue = Math.floor(min.value);
    var maxvalue = Math.floor(max.value);
    
    /* set inactive values before draw */
    min.setAttribute('data-value',minvalue);
    max.setAttribute('data-value',maxvalue);

    var avgvalue = (minvalue + maxvalue)/2;

    /* draw */
    draw(slider,avgvalue);
}

var sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.min-max-slider');
sliders.forEach( function(slider) {
    init(slider);
});
```

Mozilla Firefox is the most problematic with all range sliders, there too.
It works fine in all browsers in desktop version - chrome, opera, even ms edge, including mozilla, and in mobile versions in all browsers...excluding mozilla. I can't move the slider in mobile version in firefox.
What can be the reason? Maybe mozilla needs some more settings, like touch or something?
Maybe you already solved something like that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You need to add code to this question. Using the snippet feature. Do not try to get around the code requirement by wrapping your link in ticks. That will get this closed and most likely down voted.